# How can I make videos out of image sequences, skipping every n files?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, image-processing, avconv

I know how to make a video out of an image sequence using `ffmpeg -i %0Xd.png` or `*.png` etc. But what I'd like to do is somehow tell ffmpeg to skip every n files. E.g. if I have files numbered 0000, 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004, 0005, 0006 etc. I'd like to make a video out of files 0000, 0003, 0006, 0009 etc (i.e. taking every n==3rd file). Moving and renaming isn't really an option as I have hundreds of thousands of images, and I'd like to batch convert many different versions with different n amounts.
e.g.

- 0000, 0001, 0002... -> n1.mp4
- 0000, 0002, 0004... -> n2.mp4
- 0000, 0003, 0006... -> n3.mp4

etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a python script to do this

````
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
converts sequence of images to video
uses glob pattern and allows skipping images

---
uses [sk-video](https://github.com/scikit-video/scikit-video)
```> pip install sk-video```

backend uses ffmpeg or libav

TODO:
- add more input & output dict opts 

For full list of flags see
- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html 
- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Note: Not using opencv2.VideoWriter because it fails silently on Anaconda

'''
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division

import argparse
import glob
import os
from imageio import imread
from skvideo.io import FFmpegWriter
from tqdm import tqdm
from pprint import pprint

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input_folder', default='.', help='path to folder containing images')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--file_pattern', default='*.png', help='Unix filename pattern. For details see https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output_path', default='output.mp4', help='path to output video file')
parser.add_argument('-n', '--every', default=10, type=int, help='include every nth image. i.e. every==1 uses every image. every==2 takes every other image ')
parser.add_argument('-m', '--max_count', default=None, type=int, help='if > 0, cap at this many frames')
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', default=False, type=int, help='dump a lot of stuff to the console')

# ffmpeg args
parser.add_argument('-r', '--fps', default='30', type=str, help='frames per second')
parser.add_argument('-vcodec', default='libx264', type=str, help='output video codec')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--bitrate', default=None, type=str, help='bitrate')
parser.add_argument('-crf', default=None, type=str, help='Constant Rate Factor. The range of the CRF scale is 0–51, where 0 is lossless, 23 is the default, and 51 is worst quality possible. A lower value generally leads to higher quality, and a subjectively sane range is 17–28. Consider 17 or 18 to be visually lossless or nearly so; it should look the same or nearly the same as the input but it isnt technically lossless')
args = parser.parse_args()


#%% Get input file list
glob_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser(os.path.expandvars(args.input_folder)), args.file_pattern)

# read all files in folder matching pattern
print('Reading folder "{}"'.format(glob_path))
paths = sorted(glob.glob(glob_path))
args.stats = {'file_count_total' : len(paths) }
print(args.stats['file_count_total'], 'files found')

# skip 
if args.every > 1:
    paths = [x for i,x in enumerate(paths) if i % args.every == 0]
    args.stats['file_count_with_skip'] = len(paths)
    print(args.stats['file_count_with_skip'], 'files with skip')

# cap to max_count
if args.max_count:
    paths = paths[:args.max_count]
    args.stats['file_count_capped'] = len(paths)
    print(args.stats['file_count_capped'], 'files after cap')

#%% init video writer with parameters
inputdict = {}
outputdict = {}

if args.fps:
    inputdict['-r'] = args.fps
    outputdict['-r'] = args.fps           

if args.vcodec: outputdict['-vcodec'] = args.vcodec
if args.bitrate: outputdict['-b'] = args.bitrate
if args.crf: outputdict['-crf'] = args.crf

video_writer = FFmpegWriter(args.output_path, inputdict=inputdict, outputdict=outputdict)

#%%
print('Starting with args:')
pprint(vars(args))
for path in tqdm(paths):
    img = imread(path)
    if args.verbose: print('processing file', i, path)
    video_writer.writeFrame(img)

print('\n-')
print('Finished. Video saved at', args.output_path)

video_writer.close()
````